# Issues after integrating Google Calendar with React application

Tags: reactjs, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I have integrated the Google Calendar with my React application by following [this](https://blockchain.oodles.io/dev-blog/integrating-google-calendar-api-into-react-application/) article. (The associated Google Cloud project is still in testing state. Not published.) I have encountered the following two issues.

1. Access token expired within 3599 seconds. (around 1 hour)
2. Upon manually refreshing any page of the application, need to reinitiate gapi client. (gapi.client.getToken() returns null) But without refreshing the page if I navigate between pages still the session is kept alive and able to communicate with the calendar as I am persisting the state using localstorage.

Is that expected behavior or have I made any mistakes?